# Framework para geoprocessamento para o Brasil

Tags: maps

Encontrei vários frameworks na internet para geoprocessamento. O problema é que todos foram criados para para as regioes dos EUA.

Alguem conhece algum framework que posso chegar até a granularidade de cidade? Exemplo: 
Mapa do Brasil por regioes, ao clicar em uma região ela se desmembrada pelas regioes do IBGE.

Alguem poderia me fornecer uma luz. Obrigado

Comment: Não está claro pra mim o que você quer. Você está procurando e.g. uma base com os limites de todos os municípios brasileiros (e a informação sobre nomes, quais pertencem a cada estado, etc.)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Maps oferece a funcionalidade de resolução via *GeoCode API*; você pode combinar com Fusion Tables via [FusionTablesLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#FusionTablesLayer).

utilize o seguinte *endpoint* para pesquisas:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=[Latitude],[Longitude]&sensor=false&language=pt
```

Para resultados no Brasil, a chave `locality` indica bairro, `administrative_area_level_2` a cidade e `administrative_area_level_1` o estado.

Exemplo:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=-22.8275,-41.9753&sensor=false&language=pt

Irá retornar um JSON contendo o seguinte bloco:

```
"address_components" : [
        {
           "long_name" : "4288-4572",
           "short_name" : "4288-4572",
           "types" : [ "street_number" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Estrada Guriri",
           "short_name" : "Estr. Guriri",
           "types" : [ "route" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Cabo Frio",
           "short_name" : "Cabo Frio",
           "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Cabo Frio",
           "short_name" : "Cabo Frio",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Rio de Janeiro",
           "short_name" : "RJ",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Brasil",
           "short_name" : "BR",
           "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
        }
```

Para obtenção dos Estados que compõe o país:

http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_FusionTables_query_sidebarF_local.html?country=Brazil

Comment: Obs: Há limites de uso para esse serviço de [GeoCoder do Google](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/) ,como especificado [aqui](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/). No modo _free_ sendo: _" - API: 2500 requests per 24 hour period. - 5 requests per second."_ . Mas se seu uso não extrapolar esses limites é uma boa opção.

Comment: @Fernando correto. Adicionando ao seu comentário, este limite é por IP (caso a aplicação não se identifique) ou por aplicação.